# How to test the goodness of fit for histograms/

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, histogram

There is an histogram, $h$, with user-defined $k = 5$ bins and probabilities $[1/2, 1/3, 1/30, 1/30, 1/10]$ for the each bin.
Then $1000$ histograms were simulated. It is required to establish that the model data correspond to the original histogram. The original histogram (red) and one model histogram (blue) shown in figure.

[image]

I am looking for an approach to test the goodness of fit: the model data and the empirical histogram are drawn from the same distribution.

**Question**
What is the general approach to such a problem?

I have calculated the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric), $d$ between the original and model histograms. The distribution of this statistic is shown in the figure below. Mean of the Wasserstein distance,  $E(d) = 0.00267$.

[image]

Comment: Use a chi-squared test. For an example, including code, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/307989/919.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for comment, did I understand correctly that first I have to find a suitable distribution for the d statistic, and then apply the chi-square test?

Comment: Isn't your "model histogram" the reference distribution?

Comment: @whuber, I hope that the red histogram is my reference distribution (defined by an user) while the blue histogram was plotted on model data.